# ¿Cómo contabilizar campos de varias columnas en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada regist, en esta tabla hay varios campos, cigarette1, cigarette2, cigarette3.. pero al llenarlo cada campo de cigarette se muestra 1,2 o 3, dependiendo que cigarette sea.
Lo que quiero es sumar los campos, pero no quiero sumar 1+2+3, si no que si en la columna cigarette1 tiene 1 y la columna cigarette2 tiene un 2, entonces el resultado que busco es el 2. Espero que se de a entender. En dado caso que  cigarette1 sea igual a 0 entonces no se debe de contar, solamente las columnas que sean mayores a 0.

Estructura de tabla:

| id_u | cigarette1 | cigarette2 | cigarette3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

¿Se puede hacer esto?

Comment: o sea, buscas el número más alto de los tres campos... ¿es eso?  Y donde lo quieres mostrar?  ¿en otro campo? ¿quieres tan solo la consulta? ¿o en php?  ¿que has hecho hasta ahora y que errores te ha dado?

Comment: No,  busco que se sumen las columnas cigarette1 + cigarette2+ cigarette3, el total seria el numero 3

Comment: mmm... ¿y cuando el resultado de eso no es 3?  ¿cuando alguna de ellas sea 0?

Comment: Tienes razón, Puede ser si la columna cigarette1 es 0 solamente sumar la columna cigarette2 y cigarette3?

Comment: Puede ser lo que tu quieras, pero debes decirnos lo que quieres hacer exactamente, porque si tu tienes dudas de lo que necesitas imaginate nosotros para darte soluciones, je... se claro y conciso y quizás hasta tu mismo des con el codigo o la consulta que necesitas hacer

Comment: Gracias por lo del comentario, no lo había pensado, corregí mi pregunta, en si lo que quiero hacer es contar columnas que sean mayores a 0 y no sumar el dato que viene en el campo.

Comment: Y que problema tuviste usando el + para sumar, y fijandote si cada campo era 0 o mas para agregarlo con un if?

Comment: @gbianchi Creo que lo quiere en una consulta SQL, que quizás podria hacerse usando SUM o COUNT y CASE o cosas similares... la verdad es que ahí ya me pierdo, pero al menos ahora entiendo la pregunta :-)

Comment: @masterguru asi es, estoy viendo como se podría hacer también.

Comment: @LuisAlberto pues lo que descubras e intentes con SQL agrégalo a la pregunta, sino muchos no querran ayudarte porque parece más una tarea que un problema real con un error real... De este enlace quizás saques algo en claro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815011/mysql-count-columns-on-specific-value ... yo abandono, mysql no es mi fuerte :-)   Suerte!

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

A pesar de que intuyo un pésimo diseño (ver post-data), puedes lograr lo que pretendes sumando `1` en cada caso que cumpla la condición: que el valor de la columna sea mayor que `0`.

Algo así:

```
SELECT 
    id_u,
    SUM (
            CASE WHEN cigarette1 > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN cigarette2 > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
            CASE  WHEN cigarette3 > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 
            END
        ) AS total
FROM cigarette
GROUP BY id_u;
```

#### Código de prueba

Te dejo un fiddle con varios casos, observarás que la consulta agrupa por `id_u`.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE cigarette (
  id_u INT,
  cigarette1 INT,
  cigarette2 INT,
  cigarette3 INT
);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, cigarette1, cigarette2, cigarette3) VALUES (1,1,2,3);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, cigarette1, cigarette2, cigarette3) VALUES (2,1,null,3);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, cigarette1, cigarette2, cigarette3) VALUES (3,0,2,null);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, cigarette1, cigarette2, cigarette3) VALUES (4,null,null,null);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    id_u,
    SUM (
            CASE WHEN cigarette1 > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN cigarette2 > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
            CASE WHEN cigarette3 > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 
            END
        ) AS total
FROM cigarette
GROUP BY id_u;
```

| id_u | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gyheg3DdVpgEmXRvX2NCK8/1)

---

#### Post-Data

¿Por qué es un pésimo diseño? Porque este diseño se adaptará difícilmente a una evolución, porque hay que escribir un código complicado para obtener algo simple, porque se desaprovechan posibles índices y porque cualquier requerimiento mínimamente complejo (por ejemplo, saber cuando cigarrillos3 tienen valor `null`) será un calvario.

Consideremos un diseño donde tienes una sola columna para la cantidad (`quantity`), y agregas una columna para diferenciar los tipos de cigarrillos (`type`).

Esta sería la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE cigarette (
  id_u INT,
  quantity INT,
  type INT
);
```

Y la consulta que necesitas ahora, sería simplemente esto:

```
SELECT 
    id_u,
    SUM (
            CASE WHEN quantity > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) AS total
FROM cigarette
GROUP BY id_u;
```

Los resultados serían los mismos, a condición, claro está, de que los datos estén introducidos correctamente (ver al final el fiddle completo).

Agregemos otro nivel de complejidad: **la empresa creó un cigarillo4**. Ufff, vas a tener que meter mano a la tabla, creando una nueva columna llamada `cigarette4` y toooodas las consultas parecidas a esta tendrán que ser modificadas, agregando un `CASE` para esa nueva columna ... si hay varios millones de registros, y hay índices, agregar ooootro índice, etc.

Seguimos complicando: el cigarillo4 fue un éxito, y la empresa decide crear de golpe **10 nuevos tipos de cigarillo** ufffffff, a meter mano a la tabla de nuevo, para crear 10 nuevas columnas y a hurgar en los millones de línea de código para agregar 10 nuevos CASE WHEN.

Pero eso no es lo más grave, algo tan simple como que te pidan un reporte del tipo: ¿en qué mes del año se vendieron más cigarillos1 y menos cigarillos3? Uffffff, ¿cómo vas a lograr eso con tu diseño?

Y así, más cosas... quiero decir con todo esto que tu diseño es pésimo, y que no resistirá a la más mínima evolución o complejidad.

En el fiddle, para no liarte más, vamos simplemente a incorporar cigarrillos4 y 5 (porque los tipos son valores, no columnas de la tabla). Verás que el código se adapta perfectamente sin tocar la tabla en su diseño.  Y hay otro aspecto importante que olvidaba, imagina que cada tipo tiene unas características específicas, pues puedes relacionar a la columna `type` con otra tabla que traiga las características por cada cigarrillo.

Aquí te dejo el fiddle. Con este diseño, cualquiera de las cosas más o menos complicadas que mencioné más arriba, será relativamente fácil.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE cigarette (
  id_u INT,
  quantity INT,
  type INT
);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (1,2,2);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (1,3,3);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (2,1,1);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (2,null,2);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (2,3,3);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (3,0,1);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (3,2,2);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (3,null,3);

INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (4,null,1);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (4,null,2);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (4,null,3);

-- usuarios comprando cigarrillos del tipo 4 y 5
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (1,9,4);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (2,3,5);
INSERT INTO cigarette (id_u, quantity, type) VALUES (4,1,4);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    id_u,
    SUM (
            CASE WHEN quantity > 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) AS total
FROM cigarette
GROUP BY id_u;
```

| id_u | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gyheg3DdVpgEmXRvX2NCK8/2)

Ejemplo de algo, no tan complejo, pero que en tu diseño original sería un verdadero dolor de cabeza: ¿qué usuarios no han comprando cigarillos **superiores al tipo 3** y cuántas veces han rechazado comprarlos?

Con esta consulta lo sabrías:

```
SELECT 
    id_u,
    COUNT (*) AS total
FROM cigarette
WHERE type > 3 AND quantity = 0 OR quantity IS NULL
GROUP BY id_u;
```

**Salida:**

| id_u | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |

Pero en tu diseño original, si tuvieras varias decenas o centenas de tipos de cigarrillos **expresados en columnas**, el requerimiento **superiores al tipo 3**, que es algo muy simple y muy común, será un verdadero fastidio.